# Php how to go from day of the year to date and vice versa

Tags: php, date

How do you go in php from a nth day in the year to the date like:

```
getdatefromday(275, 2012)
```

and it outputs a date (better if an object).

And I'd like to do the opposite too, like `getdayoftheyear("21 oct 2012")`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is pretty easy all around.  You should read up on the `DateTime` object's `createFromFormat` static method [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), the `date` function [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and the `strtotime` function [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

```
/**
 * Converts the day of year of a year into a DateTime object
 * @param int $year The year
 * @param int $dayOfYear The day of year (value 1 till 365 or 1 till 366 for leap years)
 * @return \DateTime The resulting date
 */
function getDateFromDay(int $year, int $dayOfYear): \DateTime {
    // Note: "Y z" and "z Y" make a difference for leap years (last tested with PHP 8.0.3)
    $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y z', strval($year) . ' ' . strval($dayOfYear-1));
    return $date;
}
```

Comment: You should inverse the format order due to a known bug since [php 5.3.9 with leap days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35556275/phps-datetimecreatefromformat-ignores-leap-years):



DateTime::createFromFormat('Y z', strval($year) . ' ' . strval($dayOfYear));

Comment: ABSOLUTELY, I confirm you MUST inverse the format. The answer as provided is invalid.

Comment: I have edited this answer to reflect the feedback here in comments.

Answer (score 7):

Try(days starts from `0` not `1`):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y z' , '2012 275');
var_dump($date);
```

and that:

```
echo date('z', strtotime('21 oct 2012'));
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Using the format `'z Y'` causes a bug that results in skipping Leap Years in php 5.4+.  The `'Y z'` format is the workaround.  see:  https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62476

Answer (score 3):

```
$todayid = date("z");  // to get today's day of year

function dayofyear2date($tDay, $tFormat = 'd-m-Y'): string {
  $day = intval($tDay);
  $day = $day === 0 ? $day : $day - 1;
  $offset = intval(intval($tDay) * 86400);
  $str = date($tFormat, strtotime('Jan 1, ' . date('Y')) + $offset);
  return $str;
}

echo dayofyear2date($todayid);
```

day of year

Comment: I believe he wanted to get a date from the day and the year.  Not just the day.

Comment: This can still be useful for old systems that do not yet have access to DateTime. I've updated the code, which had some issues, and added support for a year attribute as well.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit old and the answer has already been accepted, but I wanted to put here an alternative way to do it, trying to use the exact formats required by the question owner:

```
// This gets the day of the year number
// given a formatted date string like
// "21 oct 2012"
function getdayoftheyear($dateString) {
  date('z', strtotime($dateString));
}
```

The other way around:

```
// This gets the date formatted in $dateFormat way
// like "Y-m-d"
// given the $dayOfTheYear and the $year in numeric form
function getdatefromday($dateFormat, $dayOfTheYear, $year) {
  date($dateFormat, mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, ($dayOfTheYear + 1), $year));
}
```

This second function uses a feature of mktime(), allowing to set whatever numbers in parameters list, because it manages overflows finding by itself the right month.
So if you call mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 32, 2015) it actually knows that the 32nd day of the 1st month is the 1st day of the 2dn month, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strtotime() to get the amount of seconds for the year value ( https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). Than at the amount of days in seconds (day * 24 * 60 * 60). Now you can use this value with date() (see first answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
function DayToTimestamp($day, $year = null)
{
    isset($year) or $year = date('Y');
    return strtotime("1 Jan $year +$day day");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getDateFromDayOfYear($dayOfYear,$year){
    return date('Y-m-d', strtotime('January 1st '.$year.' +'.$dayOfYear.' days'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From a number day to a date, in this case a i am using a for to get al days in specific format "20-01-01", if you don't want this don't use the format.

```
for($i = 0; $i < 365; $i++){
    $date = date_create_from_format( 'Y z' , '2020 '.$i);
    print_r($date->format('y-m-d'));
    print_r("\n");
}
```

Other case from date to the number of the specific date is like:

```
$date=date('z', strtotime('2023-01-01') + 1);
print_r($date);
$date=date('z', strtotime('2023-12-31') + 1);
print_r($date);
```

In the example for the first and last day of specific year.

Answer (score -2):

Getting the day of the year is easy.  Just use the date function with the correct parameter as [documented in the manual](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) (it returns 0 for Jan-1 to 365 for Dec-31 on a leap year).

Going the other way will need a bit of creativity.