# PHP's DateTime::createFromFormat ignores leap years

Tags: php, date

I have to convert a DayOfYear-value in a Date.

I tried following for the 70th day of 2016:

```
php -r 'var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat("z Y","69 2016"));'
```

> ```
> class DateTime#1 (3) {
>   public $date =>
>   string(26) "2016-03-11 14:21:07.000000"
>   public $timezone_type =>
>   int(3)
>   public $timezone =>
>   string(3) "UTC"
> }
> ```

('z' is null-based)

But that's wrong. It should be the 2016-03-10!

Is it a PHP-Bug?

Comment: Seems to be a known bug since 5.3.9: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62476

Comment: It is a bug. Inverted format works: `::createFromFormat( "Y z", "2016 69" )`

Comment: Faced this today in 2020 :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a bug. (As @aioros remarks in a comment, it's [bug #62476](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62476).)

You can, however, circumvent it if you create the `DateTime` object for the first day of the year then add the number of days you need:

```
$date = 
    DateTime::createFromFormat("z Y","0 2016", new DateTimeZone("UTC"))
    ->add(new DateInterval("P69D"))
;
var_dump($date);
```

It displays:

```
class DateTime#2 (3) {
  public $date =>
  string(26) "2016-03-10 14:46:37.000000"
  public $timezone_type =>
  int(3)
  public $timezone =>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
```

**Update:**

Another workaround, suggested in a comment on [PHP bug #62476](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62476) is to put the year first:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat("Y z","2016 69");
```

This way it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for solution and explanation!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. When i try to convert the current date: 
DateTime::createFromFormat('Y z', '2020 189') it returns '2020-07-08 08:19:31.000000'. When i look at the day numbers for 2020 i see that July 7th is day number 189, but the createFromFormat returns july 8th. :/