# Duplicate days count in the month of january

Tags: php

php calendar for year 2016 shows correct days when i change it to 2017 it shows repeated days in month of january. Now i have hardcoded year 2016 and 2017, later i will change this to system date.Someone please help me?

```
<?php 
    $dates = getDates(date("Y")); //gets system default date, if i change this to date(2016) works fine, when i change to 2017 it shows repeated days entry for january month.

    $weekdays = array('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'); //prints weeks.
    $monthPrints = array('01'=>'January','02'=>'February','03'=>'March','04'=>'April','05'=>'May','06'=>'June','07'=>'July','08'=>'August','09'=>'September','10'=>'October','11'=>'November','12'=>'December'); ?>  // prints month string.

<?php foreach($dates as $month => $weeks) { ?>
    <?php print_r($monthPrints[$month]); ?>
    <table id="<?= $month ?>">    
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo implode('</th><th>', $weekdays); ?></th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach($weeks as $week => $days){ ?>
        <tr>
         <?php foreach($weekdays as $day){ ?>
            <td>
                <?php echo isset($days[$day]) ? $days[$day] : '&nbsp'; ?>
            </td>               
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
    <?php  }?>
    <?php
    function getDates($year)
    {
        $dates = array();

        for($i = 1; $i <= 366; $i++){
            $month = date('m', mktime(0,0,0,1,$i,$year));
            $wk = date('W', mktime(0,0,0,1,$i,$year));
            $wkDay = date('D', mktime(0,0,0,1,$i,$year));
            $day = date('d', mktime(0,0,0,1,$i,$year));

            $dates[$month][$wk][$wkDay] = $day;
        } 

        return $dates;
    }
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `for` cycle in `getDates()` goes up to 366. Change this number to 365 and everything will be fine.
I guess it's because 2016 was bissextile, while 2017 is not.

You should use something different to get the date from the day of the year, check out this one: [Php how to go from day of the year to date and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735528/php-how-to-go-from-day-of-the-year-to-date-and-vice-versa)