# do the same by writing less code

Tags: php, forms, display

I have the following code

```
$day = $_GET['day'];

$month = $_GET['month'];

if($day=='1'&&$month=='January'){
    echo "<img src=\"playingCard/spades/13.png\" alt='' />";
} elseif ($day=='2'&&$month=='January'){
    echo "<img src=\"playingCard/spades/12.png\" alt='' />";
} elseif ($day=='3'&&$month=='January'||$day=='1'&&$month=='February'){
    echo "<img src=\"playingCard/spades/11.png\" alt='' />";
} elseif ($day=='4'&&$month=='January'){
    echo "<img src=\"playingCard/spades/10.png\" alt='' />";
} ....
```

and there is a form where you can input a number for the day and a value for the month. 
What I would like to do is display a specific playing card on a specific date.
For example

```
January 1st = king of spades 
January 2nd = Queen of spades
February 1st = Jack of spades
and so on
```

I have a folder where I've saved 4 sub-folders with the images of the 4 siut of the playing cards.

So far the code is working, but it will be tremendously long by doing 365 days, is there a simple way to do it with less code?

Hope I was clear enough.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you explain the pattern better? How do I know what card, say, March 13th would be?

Comment: As EdmCoff says, what is the pattern? I would probably say use arrays and or date and months as folder structure

Comment: " 365 days" don't forget leap years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, without the pattern, it's hard to give a perfect answer... but if you want to wrap through the deck over and over with a seemingly random but predictable order, you could use mod (%) with a switch statment:

```
//get numerical day of the year
$dayofyear = date('z', mktime(12, 0, 0, $month, $day, date('Y')));
$suit = '';

//will result in 1 on jan-1, 2 on jan-2, up to 13, then back to 1.
$card = ($dayofyear % 13) + 1;
$nSuit = ($dayofyear % 4) + 1;

switch ($nSuit) {
   case 1:
     $suit = 'spades';
     break;
   case 2:
     $suit = 'hearts';
     break;
   case 3:
     $suit = 'clubs';
     break;
   case 4:
     $suit = 'diamonds';
     break;
}

echo "<img src=\"playingCard/" . $suit . "/" . $card . ".png\" alt='' />";
```

this would result in

```
spades    1
hearts    2
clubs     3
diamonds  4
spades    5
hearts    6
clubs     7
diamonds  8
spades    9
hearts   10
clubs    11
diamonds 12
spades   13
hearts    1
clubs     2
diamonds  3
```

Answer (score 3):

I have no PHP interpreter handy, but this should give you a general idea (or it might just work after minimal edits):

```
$day = $_GET['day'];

$month = $_GET['month'];

$images = array (
    "January" => array ( 1 => "path to image", 2 => "path to another image", ... ),
    "February" => array ( 1 => "path to image", 2 => "path to another image", ... ),
    ...
  );

echo $images[$month][$day];
```

The `$images` variable could be moved to a separate `.php` file and the whole thing would look kind of like the following (name the file what you want):

months_initialiser.php:

```
<?php
$images = array (
    "January" => array ( 1 => "path to image", 2 => "path to another image", ... ),
    "February" => array ( 1 => "path to image", 2 => "path to another image", ... ),
    ...
  );
?>
```

Your actual file:

```
<?php
$day = $_GET['day'];

$month = $_GET['month'];

include 'months_initialiser.php';

echo $images[$month][$day];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't define a regular pattern for which card should be displayed, you could put the paths to the image files in a 366-element array, then use the [day of the year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735528/php-how-to-go-from-day-of-the-year-to-date-and-vice-versa) to index the array.

If you *can* define a regular pattern, you only need a 52-element array, then take `$day_of_year % 52` to get the index. (This would be a lot less code to define the array, but from your example it doesn't look like you have a regular pattern.)